# Finding word's bounding box on a low quality image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, bounding-box

I'm trying to get a bounding box for the word "ЛИЛИЯ" in this image, using opencv.

[image: example image to process]
<sub>(source: [litprom.ru](http://litprom.ru/3.png))</sub>

I am already experimenting with `cv::findContours()` and different thresholding alogrithms for couple of days, but can not get any satisfying results.

So, what do I know about this word:

- letters are of similar size;
- letters' height is in range: 40px — 90px;
- word is oriented horizontaly (±5˚);
- there is one and only one word on this image;
- this word does not intersect image's border (it's fully visible);
- different parts of image may have different luminosity;
- hotspots (totally white areas) may be present on an image.

English is not my native language, so I'm sorry if the question is not properly explained.
If someone needs more images to answer this question, I have at least a dozen more.

Comment: Check out stroke width transform. That is used to text detection.

Comment: @Diana, thank you — now I'm reading about SWT and it looks promising. I will need some time to implement it in Obj-C and I will tell you if it worked.

Comment: hi, may i know if the word will change? please upload more images as well.

Comment: @Diana, stroke width transform is not the easiest thing to implement — it was two days of pain and humiliation. But it works like charm! 

Please, post your comment as an answer and I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: @Stanislav I'm happy everything worked out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out stroke width transform. That is used to text detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your image with [adaptiveThreshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html). You should use a blocksize a little bit bigger than your biggest character. I tried on your image with 91 and it gave good results. Then you can use FindContours and filter the blobs/contours using their height. Note that the letters will still be connected one to another so you cannot really filter using the width.